# Javascript add row with increment id with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have a add new row script where it clones the entire "tr" increments the id + 1 and then clears the values. All works great but the goal is to have one of the text inputs be tied to jquery autocomplete function.

Javascript:

```
$("#add-row").click(function(){
    var lastRow = $('#findings-table tbody>tr:last');
    var cloned = lastRow.clone();
    cloned.find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/; 
        var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
        var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

        $(this).attr('id', newId);
    });
    cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    cloned.find("textarea").val('');
    cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);        
});


$(function() {
         $("#code1").autocomplete({
            source: "/search_ajax.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#code1').val(ui.item.id);
                //$('#descrip2').val(ui.item.notes);
            }
        });

        $("#code2").autocomplete({
            source: "/search_ajax.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#code2').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });

        $("#code3").autocomplete({
            source: "/search_ajax.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#code3').val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
<table id="findings-table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
         <th>Code</th>
         <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
         <td><input style="width: 70px;" type="text" id="code1" name="code[]" class="form-control"></td>
         <td><textarea cols="30" rows="3" id="descrip1" name="descrip[]"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click add a row it duplicates correctly and then I get id="code2" then id="code3", ect.

My issue is the code2 id and code3 id should populate with autocomplete drop down info from search_ajax.php. The code1 id works correctly. I am assuming it has something to do with code1 id is already there on page load but the added rows aren't? Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to bind the autocomplete that to the freshly added elements.  You could do that at the end of the `$("#add-row").click()` function.

Comment: @AdamKonieska thanks. Is it possible to bind it dynamically instead of just adding 10 of them. Something like: `$("#code"+newId).autocomplete({`

Comment: Char Priddle is right, after dinamcally insert a new element, you need to re-bind the events you need for each new element. If is a click event, you can add to document too, avoiding to re-bind all mannualy.

Ex: 
$(document).on('click','your-element',function(){
    //your action here
});

Comment: @ChadPriddle thats exactly how you'd do it, yes.

Comment: @AdamKonieska do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the bindings dynamically at the end of your `$("#add-row").click()` function.  Something like this should work:

```
$("#add-row").click(function(){
    var lastRow = $('#findings-table tbody>tr:last');
    var cloned = lastRow.clone();
    cloned.find('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/; 
        var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
        index = (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);
        var newId = aIdParts[1] + index;
        $(this).attr('id', newId);        
    });
    cloned.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    cloned.find("textarea").val('');
    cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);    

    addBinding(index);


});



function addBinding(index) {
    $("#code" + index).autocomplete({
        source: "/search_ajax.php",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
}


addBinding(1); //for the element that already exsists
```

Here it is in a JS Fiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/me8bqqx2/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: If the `$("#code" + newId).autocomplete({` is located inside the click function how does the `code2` then trigger the autocomplete trigger the ajax request? I tried your code and it's not triggering the ajax request.

Comment: @ChadPriddle I didn't look closely at the regex you were using, so I didn't see that `newId` was not an integer value.  I updated the answer and the JS fiddle seems to be running everything until it hits the jQuery UI, so your Ajax request should fire, but I'm not sure how you have everything set up so it would be difficult to reproduce any further.

Comment: this worked perfectly! Thanks so much. The regex threw me off as well since I found the code from another stack thread